# npm install mongoose : errors out with node-gyp error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-gyp

I'm having difficulty installing the Mongodb (native driver) or Mongoose (which requires and extends it), and it keeps erroring out here:

---

I have tried rolling back my version of node to 0.10.x using nvm, that didn't do it.

```
brianboyko@Boyko-Linux ~/boykofork $ npm install --save mongoose
npm WARN package.json boykofork@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json boykofork@1.0.0 No README data
/
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /home/brianboyko/boykofork/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/brianboyko/boykofork/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:27:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c:28:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function ‘authenticate_gss_client_wrap’:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:348:19: warning: variable ‘server_conf_flags’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
                   ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:687:0: warning: ignenter code hereoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/brianboyko/boykofork/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/brianboyko/boykofork/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
mongoose@4.1.9 node_modules/mongoose
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.12
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.10)
```